# Java timer not working correctly

Tags: java, timer

```
....

public class mainClass {
    public mainClass(){
        Timer time = new Timer();
        mainClass.calculate calculate = new mainClass.calculate();
        time.schedule(calculate, 1 * 1000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new mainClass();
    }

    class calculate extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("working..");

        }
    }
}
```

I saw only one times "working.." message in the console.I want to saw every second "working.." whats the problem on code? and my another problem i want to running every second my own method but how?

Sory for my bad english..

Comment: You should really capitalize your classes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29) only runs the TimerTask once, after the number of milliseconds in the second argument.

To repeatedly run the TimerTask, you need to use one of the other `schedule()` overloads such as [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29), for example:

```
time.schedule(calculate, 1000, 1000);
```

which schedules the task to be executed 1000 milliseconds from now, and to repeat every 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: time.schedule(calculate, 0, 1 * 1000); now working correctly thank you all

Comment: +1 awesome quick and accurate response... though you should use up-to-date API specs.

Answer (score 2):

It is supposed to be one time according to the documentation:

> public void schedule(TimerTask task,
>                        long delay) Schedules the specified task for execution after the specified delay. Parameters: task - task to be
>   scheduled. delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be
>   executed. Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if delay is negative, or
>   delay + System.currentTimeMillis() is negative. IllegalStateException
>   - if task was already scheduled or cancelled, or timer was cancelled.

you probably want to call

> public void schedule(TimerTask task,
>                        long delay,
>                        long period)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait in your main thread for the timer to be fired. The JVM will exit when all the non daemon threads are completed. The thread that runs your main method is actually the only non damon thread so you should make it wait until your work is complete.

Change your main method like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     new mainClass();
     Thread.sleep(2 * 1000); // wait longer than what the timer 
                             // should wait so you can see it firing.
 }
```

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question of how to make the task repeat.

Comment: From the docs: `By default, the task execution thread does not run as a daemon thread, so it is capable of keeping an application from terminating.` So this would only be applicable if the Timer constructor `Timer(boolean isDaemon)` was used.

Comment: Yea .. i wrote this in a hurry. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
zaman.schedule(calculate, 0, 1000);
```

to schedule the timer to run more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The version of `Timer.schedule()` which you are using only executes the task once after a delay. You need to use [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long, long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) to cause the task to repeat.